# What is the name of this concept in algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

since I'm a bad algebraist, I have to relearn field theory. In this process, I came across the following concept:

For two field extensions $L \supset K$, $M \supset K$ there may be a $K$-isomorphism $L \to M$ (i.e. $L$ and $M$ are isomorphic via an isomorphism that leaves elements of $K$ fixed). I'm learning from van der Waerden's book (since it's one of the best on field theory) and he calls $L$ and $M$ *equivalent* field extensions. But I couldn't find this term with this meaning anywhere in the internet (neither in English nor in my mother tongue German).

So, since it's quite an old book, I thought maybe that there is now a new term for this, and I would be glad if anybody could help me out.

Comment: I'd call then $K$-isomorphic...

Answer (score 2):

There is a [category of field extensions of a field $k$](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09FT) whose objects are field extensions of $k$. In your case, you have two objects $L$ and $M$ of this category, and an isomorphism in the category.

Comment: Interesting link.